# Saving content of WPF Image control after drawing lines/points/texts

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bitmap, wpf-controls

I have created a custom image class that overrides the `onRender(DrawingContext dc)` method. In this method I use the `drawingContext` to draw lines, dots and text into the image. Until then everything works. Now I want to **save the image including the drawn elements** in a folder. I have searched very long, but unfortunately found nothing suitable. Does anyone have an idea how I can save the image with the drawn elements as a bitmap?

Edit: This is what I have now:

```
cachedTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)ActualWidth, 
(int)ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

cachedTargetBitmap.Render(this);
```

```
var encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(Image1.TargetBitmap);
encoder.Frames.Add(frame);

using (var stream = File.Create(string.Format("{0}\\Left.bmp", SavePath)))
{
     encoder.Save(stream);
}

var encoder2 = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
BitmapFrame frame2 = BitmapFrame.Create(Image2.TargetBitmap);
encoder2.Frames.Add(frame2);

using (var stream = File.Create(string.Format("{0}\\Right.bmp", SavePath)))
{
encoder2.Save(stream);
}
```

I have 2 WPF Images and I draw lines, points and text on them. At saving the images as Bitmap, the first image is saved without the text, but with the points and lines and it is shifted to the right. The second image is saved completely black.

Comment: Render you custom control into a RenderTargetBitmap, then save that by means of a BitmapEncoder.

Comment: I just did something like this and I was only partially successful. I have 2 WPF Images and I draw lines, points and text on them. At saving the images as Bitmap, the first image is saved without the text, but with the points and lines and it is shifted to the right. The second image is saved completely black.

Comment: @Clemens `cachedTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                cachedTargetBitmap.Render(this);`

Comment: In case you want to save semi-transparent images, do not use BmpBitmapEncoder. Use a PngBitmapEncoder instead.

Comment: Any chance you could share a [mcve] by including a demo version of your custom image class?

Answer (score -1):

If you are dispaying it in a picturebox, you can do something as follows - Also be nice if you shared your current code.

```
 Bitmap snapshot As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
 PictureBox1.Image.Save("Path here\testImage.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a solution in WPF, this is for WinForms. Doesn't apply.

Comment: Jimi is right. And I dont think that my code is necessary for this question cause its something general.

Comment: Yes sorry - didnt see the tag.